# Program extraction using native integers/words (not bignums) from Isabelle theory

Tags: isabelle

This question comes in a context where Isabelle is used with formal software development in mind more than with pure maths theorization in mind (and from a standalone developer's context).

Seems at best, SML programs generated from an Isabelle theory, use SML's `IntInf.int`, not the native integer type, which is `Int.int`; even if `Code_Target_Int`, `Code_Binary_Nat` or `Code_Target_Nat` is used. Investigation of these theories sources seems to confirm it's all it can do. Native platform integers may be required for multiple reasons, including efficiency and the case the SML imperative program is to be optionally translated into an imperative language subset (ex. C or Ada), which is relevant when the theory relies on the `Imperative_HOL` theory. The `codegen.pdf` document which comes with the Isabelle distribution, did not help with it, except in suggesting the first of the options below.

Options may be:

- Not using Isabelle's `int` and `nat` and re‑create a new numeric type from scratch, then use the `code_printing` commands (with its `type_constructor` and `constant`) to give it the native platform representation and operations (implies inclusion of range limitations in some way in the theory) : must be tedious, although unlikely error‑prone I hope, due to the formal environment. Note this does seems feasible with Isabelle's own `int` and `nat`… it makes code generation fails, and nothing tells which constants are missing in the `code_printing` command.
- If the SML program is to be compiled directly (ex. with MLTon), tweak the SML environment with a replacement `IntInf` structure : may be unsafe or not feasible, and still requires to embed the range limitations in the theory, so the previous options may finally be better than this one.
- Touch the generated program to change `IntInf` into `Int` : easy, but it is safe? (at least, `IntInf` implements the same signature as `Int` do, so may be it's safe). As above, requires to specifies bounds in the theory in some way, it's OK with this.
- Dive into Isabelle internals : surely unreasonable, even worse than the second option.
- There exist a `Word` theory, but according to some readings, it's seems not suited for that purpose.

Are they other known options not listed here? Are they comments on the listed options?

If there is no ready‑to‑cook solutions (I feel there is no at the time), what hints or tracks would be best known? (ex. links to documents, mentions of concepts).

### Update

Points #2 and #3 of the list, may be OK (if it really is) only if there is a single integer type. If the program use more than only one, it's not applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly generating native words from Isabelle `int` would be unsound, because your formalisation would not take overflow into account where it exists in reality.

It looks like the AFP entry `Native_Word` does what you want, though:
http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/Native_Word.shtml

Comment: Thanks Isf37. I will have a look then will select you're answer if it this theory looks OK. Thanks for this reference I've never noticed anyway.

Comment: Unless I've missed something, it's for unsigned integers, while may still be a good starting point for signed integers. There are also some issues, like still using bignums at some place, documented in the PDF. The latter is probably solvable using multiply instead of shift (when expecting words, not integers).

Comment: Native_Words is for unsigned integers, but signed integers could be done similarly. bignums are used in several places as an interface between Isabelle-generated types (like `nat` and `int`) and machine words; in particular, bit indices and shifts use `nat` in Isabelle and therefore might not fit into a machine integer, so they are first converted to `IntInf` and then to the machine integer type that the target language expects.